# Send a Graphics object over the network

Tags: java, oop, network-programming

In the context of a networked, centralized game I am designing, the best would be to perform the graphic context update on the server, and send a clone of the Graphics object to clients so the display process is straightforward; no prior calculations to do.

Is there a way I could achieve exactly what I am describing or I have to alter my design and come up with another way of data distribution?

Comment: Sure you can, read my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using java on both sides:

```
File tmp = File.createTempFile("test", ".xml");
XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tmp)));
e.writeObject(WIlopuGraphicsObject);
e.close(); // there's now an XML representation of your graphic in the file named tmp.getName()
```

To decode it:

```
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmp)); // tmp from above
XMLDecoder d = new XMLDecoder(stream);
WIlopuGraphicsObject graphic = (WIlopuGraphicsObject)d.readObject();
d.close();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think the question is about a java.awt.Graphics object, not an application-specific class.

Comment: OPs presumably using a wrapper around java.awt.Graphics, though [XMLEncoder creates archives of any Java objects -- even when they don't follow the JavaBeans conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html), so I'm unsure why the lot of you are making a distinction

Comment: @hd1: Thank you hd1. The idea as is at the moment doesn't involve a wrapper class around Java's Graphics, but if necessity be, I guess I could do that. Also, could you please expand on that "stream" you pass onto the XMLDecoder constructor? It's my first time dealing with XLM in Java.

Comment: Hello @hd1. One thing I don't get: On the receiving end, what is "tmp"? How did you get it from the soclet? And why did you encode it into XML specifically?

Comment: It's the same as the tmp in the sending end. XMLEncoder returns an XML-encoded representation of the object, which XMLDecoder decodes.

Comment: @hd1: Well, I mean, how did get it from the `InputStream`on the client's end? How can I get to it? Remember, this is a client-server communication over a socket.

Comment: socket.getInputStream() instead of the FileInputStream(tmp) and socket.getOutputStream() instead of the FileOutputStream(tmp)

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured, so I was confused. Thanks!